# ERROR itms 90682

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте, после обновления Xcode архивную свой проект и выдает ошибку, что с этим делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Терминал
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60919

Comment: А зачем это?...

Comment: в смысле зачем? там ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: А, все зашла, спасибо за ссылку

Comment: Дошла до 4 пункта и не понимаю что в терминал писать, написала путь к этому файлу, а он пишет "No such file or directory"

Comment: надо написать путь в вашему .app файлу в той папке, где он лежит

Comment: А в 6 пункте как найти этот инструмент assetutil?

Comment: я думал он всегда с xcode идет. можете просто в терминале написать assetutil и посмотреть найдет ли

Comment: Сверху приложила картинку что мне написали, если в терминале ввести

Comment: есть у вас assetutil - не надо его искать, система в курсе, где он находится

Comment: а как с помощью него найти эти активы? ничего не пойму(

Comment: ладно, давайте так. загрузите сюда свой Payload/Nuclear World.app/Assets.car я сам посмотрю какие у вас там изображения надо менять

Comment: Смотрите, я так понимаю, что все изображения должны быть 8 бит/канал?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: и обязательно RGB?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45869/discussion-between-max-mikheyenko-and-leci).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогли разобраться в вопросе) Нужно Deployment Target поставить 9.3